# How can I upload files to a shared Dropbox folder?

Tags: dropbox

My friend shared a folder with me on Dropbox. I got the link of that folder. However, As shown in the screenshot below, there is no upload button in the folder's page.

[image: Dropbox folder page]

My question is: how to upload files to this shared folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a shared link to that folder.

Your friend need to share the folder with you with "**Can edit**" option selected.

NOT, share a link, and not shared with "Can view" option.